# How to draw the object in the table sapui5

Tags: javascript, xml, sapui5

I have a controller which establishes the following data:

```
    onInit : function () {
        var oData = {
            contactsList:[
                {
                    id: 123,
                    vendorNum: 7896585,
                    recipientType: 'Strong'
                },
                {
                    id: 234,
                    vendorNum: 2350056,
                    recipientType: 'Hard'
                }
            ]
        };

        var oModel = new JSONModel(oData);
        this.getView().setModel(oModel, "modelName");
    },
```

It is xml-view, which renders the data:

```
        <Table class="tableList" items="{path: '/modelName/contactsList/'}">
            <columns>
                <Column width="3rem">
                    <CheckBox id="checkAll" />
                </Column>
                <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" demandPopin="true">
                    <Text text="{i18n>vendorNum}"/>
                </Column>
                <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" demandPopin="true">
                    <Text text="{i18n>recipientType}"/>
                </Column>
            </columns>
            <items>
                <ColumnListItem>
                    <cells>

                    </cells>
                    <cells>
                        <Text text="{modelName>vendorNum}"/>
                    </cells>
                    <cells>
                        <Text text="{modelName>recipientType}"/>
                    </cells>
                </ColumnListItem>
            </items>
        </Table>
```

As a result, nothing happens, he says that there is no data.

Explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Since your model is not named, the syntax `{modelName>property}` is wrong. If you want to use that syntax, do `this.getView().setModel(oModel, "modelName");`. Also, binding does not work for every property. ID is one of them.

Comment: Not only that, but you have a CheckBox in your column header which does not make sense either. But your **real** error is in this line: `<Table class="tableList" items="{path: '/contactsList'}">>` and this error is easy to spot ;-) Better validate your code first, then error would then be visible immediately

Comment: @Marc, I edited the question. At the moment, I get the message "No data", but the cap table is displayed. What is now wrong?

Comment: Your  `items` binding is wrong: change it to `{path: 'contactsList>/contactsList'}` (or simply `{contactsList>/contactsList}`) If you use named models, remember to always prefix your binding with `modelname>`

Comment: @Qualiture, Oh, I fix it, thank's

Comment: To get your checkboxes working, just give your Table `mode=MultiSelect` (or `SingleSelect`). No need to code that extra column yourself. See this example: https://openui5beta.netweaver.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.TableVerticalAlignment/preview

Comment: @Mark, Thank you very much, this is what I need)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally a model binding consists of two parts:

1. An optional model name and
2. The non-optional binding path, which can be absolute (starting with `/`) or relative.

For an aggregation binding like the one in your table example you need one binding on the table to set the location of your items and relative binding to set the cell properties.

---

Let's rename your model to make it a bit easier to understand:

```js
this.getView().setModel(new JSONModel({
    contactsList: [
        {
            vendorNum: 7896585
        }
    ]
}), "contactModel");
```

For your table, the items-binding should be absolute and contain the model name:

```xml
<Table items="{contactModel>/contactsList}">
```

The bindings in the table cells are then relative but contain the same model name:

```xml
<Text text="{contactModel>vendorNum}" />
```